# getContentResolver query cause CursorWrapperInner warning

Tags: android, warnings, android-cursor

On 4.0.3, Code below cause warning "W/CursorWrapperInner(11252): Cursor finalized without prior close()".

```
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
    getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

In sorce, I found the warning where it come from, anyone tell me how to avoid as i doubt it related to some weird problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also experienced this weird issue. I'm using a ContentProvider to provide me with a Cursor and a CursorLoader to handle the fetching in my Fragment/Activities. So I'm doing everything "to the book".

I experienced this warning message using a 4.1.1 device, but it seems to have gone away on my Nexus 7 which is 4.2. Personally I would not take any serious notice of this warning.

Update:
I was testing my code with Android v2.2 and I got a full stacktrace from this error. It turned out that my code was fetching another Cursor (not the one fetched using a Loader) and it was this that was the offending code. Closing this manually did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code returns a Cursor object:

```
getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

It's odd that you are performing a query but ignoring the result. The only purpose of performing a query is to get the results in a Cursor. You should store that into a variable like so:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

Then you can use the cursor to get whatever data you need and when you are done with it call:

```
cursor.close();
```

You can close the cursor in `Activity#onDestroy()` or earlier, but you must close it before the Activity is completely finished or you will see this warning. This is because a Cursor is backed by memory in another process and you don't want to leak that memory.