# ContentLoader on MediaStore, and automatic refresh/reload

Tags: android, mediastore, contentobserver

I'm querying the MediaStore, [joining Images and Thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511461/joining-cursors-and-sorting), and loading in a GridView. This works fine enough, but I can't figure out how to update my app when a new photo appears in the MediaStore (typically when taken by the camera). The default gallery app automatically loads the new image, but my app does nothing. I've tried registering content observers, and I've even tried adding a manual "refresh" menu button, but the only way to load the new image is to stop and restart the entire app.

**Edit**
Actually, that's not entirely true. If I take a new photo, and switch to some other gallery app or widget, then this other app will load the new image (thumbnail) and my app will then suddenly also refresh. This indicates that I *am* observing *some* events, right, since the new thumbnail eventually appears automatically in my app? Maybe I'm just not observing the right ones. I just don't understand how the manual refresh accomplishes nothing.

I'm posting the relevant java files, maybe someone can see what I'm forgetting, or am doing wrong?

I'm at a loss, been working at this for quite some time, so please forgive me if the post is too vague. I'll try to add whatever details are missing.

### PhotoFragment

```
package com.example.android.galleri.app;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.android.galleri.app.data.PhotoContract;


public class PhotoFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private final static int LOADER_ID = 87;
    private PhotoAdapter mPhotoAdapter;
    private int mPosition;
    private GridView mGridView;
    private TextView mEmptyView;
    private int count_mem = -1;
    private static final String SELECTED_KEY = "POSITION";
    private boolean mTwoPane;
    private boolean DF_hidden = false;

    // these are the data we want from MediaStore
    private final static String[] THUMBNAIL_COLUMNS = {
            PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_THUMB_ID,
            PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_DATA,
            PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE_ID,
            PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_TITLE,
            PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_DESC,
            PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_DATE
    };

    static final int COL_THUMB_ID = 0;
    static final int COL_THUMB_DATA = 1;
    static final int COL_THUMB_IMAGE_ID = 2;
    static final int COL_TITLE = 3;
    static final int COL_DESC = 4;
    static final int COL_DATE = 5;

    public void setTwoPaneUI(boolean pTwoPane) {
        mTwoPane = pTwoPane;
    }

    // interfaces
    public interface Callback {
        public void onItemSelected(Uri photoUri);
    }
    public interface FragmentCallback {
        public void onTaskDone(int count);
    }


    public PhotoFragment() {
    }

    public int getPosition() {
       return mPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }


    public void onNewCameraEvent() {
        Log.v("JOAKIM", "PhotoFragment.onNewCameraEvent() triggering a refresh...");
        restartLoader();
    }
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241705/calling-a-activity-method-from-broadcastreceiver-in-android
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // internet lost alert dialog method call from here...
            Log.v("JOAKIM", "PhotoFragment.broadcastReceiver.onReceive() captured the image!");
            onNewCameraEvent();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("TRIGGER_A_REFRESH"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }




    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.photofragment, menu);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            Log.v("JOAKIM", "PhotoFragment.onOptionsItemSelected() refresh clicked");

            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271271/android-callback-asynctask-to-fragmentnot-activity
            ManualRefreshTask refreshTask = new ManualRefreshTask(
                    new FragmentCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTaskDone(int count) {
                            // loader is restarted every time, since I couldn't
                            // get the logic to work 100%
                            restartLoader();
                            /*
                            // if the number of images has changed, restart loader
                            if (count != count_mem) restartLoader();
                            */
                            count_mem = count;
                        }
                    });
            refreshTask.execute(getActivity().getContentResolver());
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void restartLoader() {
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if (mPosition != GridView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            outState.putInt(SELECTED_KEY, mPosition);
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mPhotoAdapter = new PhotoAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_photo);
        gridView.setAdapter(mPhotoAdapter);

        mEmptyView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_empty);
        mGridView = gridView;

        // handle user clicking on an image
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                if (cursor != null) {
                    Uri baseUri = PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.buildPhotoUriWithId(cursor.getLong(COL_THUMB_IMAGE_ID));
                    Log.v("JOAKIM", "PhotoFragment.onItemClick() image_id = " + cursor.getLong(COL_THUMB_IMAGE_ID)
                            + ", baseUri = " + baseUri.toString());

                    // make sure detail fragment is visible
                    if (mTwoPane) showDetailFragment();
                    else Utility.setPosition(position);  // else (single-pane): store position clicked!

                    ((Callback)getActivity()).onItemSelected(baseUri);
                }
                mPosition = position;
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(SELECTED_KEY)) {
            mPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_KEY);
        }

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        Uri thumbs_uri = PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.CONTENT_URI;
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), thumbs_uri, THUMBNAIL_COLUMNS,
                null,null,  // read everything (all thumbnails)
                PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_THUMB_ID + " DESC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor != null) {

            // register observer onto cursor
            cursor.setNotificationUri(getActivity().getContentResolver(), PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.CONTENT_URI);

            mPhotoAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
            if (mPosition != GridView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                mGridView.setSelection(mPosition);  // scroll into view
            }
        }

        // save (set) cursor in Utility
        Utility.setCursor(cursor);

        if (cursor == null) {
            mEmptyView.setText("No Images on Device");
            mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (mTwoPane) {
                mGridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                hideDetailFragment();
            }

        } else {
            mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (mTwoPane) {
                mGridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                showDetailFragment();
            }
        }
    }


    public void hideDetailFragment() {
        if (!DF_hidden) {
            Log.v("JOAKIM", "PhotoFragment.onLoadFinished() remove detail framelayout");
            FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.photo_detail_container);
            container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            DF_hidden = true;

            Display display = ((WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
            int rotation = display.getRotation();

            int numColumns = 10;
            if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) numColumns = 8;
            else numColumns = 10;

            mGridView.setNumColumns(numColumns);
        }
    }
    public void showDetailFragment() {
        if (DF_hidden) {
            Log.v("JOAKIM", "PhotoFragment.onLoadFinished() show detail fragment");
            FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.photo_detail_container);
            container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            DF_hidden = false;

            mGridView.setNumColumns(6);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
        mPhotoAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }


}
```

### PhotoContract

```
package com.example.android.galleri.app.data;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class PhotoContract {

    public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.example.android.galleri.app";

    public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY);

    public static final String PATH_THUMBS = "thumbs";
    public static final String PATH_PHOTO = "photo";
    public static final String PATH_COMMENT = "comment";
    //public static final String PATH_AUTHOR = "author";

    // define updateable fields (where to update them)
    public static final String TARGET_EXIF = "EXIF";
    public static final String TARGET_MEDIASTORE = "MediaStore.Images.Media";
    public static final String TARGET_MEDIASTORE_THUMBS = "MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails";

    public static final class ThumbEntry {

        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =
                BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(PATH_THUMBS).build();

        public static final String COLUMN_THUMB_ID = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID;
        public static final String COLUMN_DATA = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA;
        public static final String COLUMN_IMAGE_ID = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID;

        public static final String COLUMN_IMAGE_PK = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
        public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE;
        public static final String COLUMN_DESC = MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION;
        public static final String COLUMN_DATE = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;

        public static final String CONTENT_TYPE =
                ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_THUMBS;

        public static final Map<String, String> COL_TYPES;
        static {
            COL_TYPES = new HashMap<String, String>();
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_THUMB_ID, TARGET_MEDIASTORE_THUMBS);
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_DATA, TARGET_MEDIASTORE_THUMBS);
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_IMAGE_ID, TARGET_MEDIASTORE_THUMBS);
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_TITLE, TARGET_MEDIASTORE);
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_DESC, TARGET_MEDIASTORE);
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_DATE, TARGET_MEDIASTORE);
        }
    }

    public static final class PhotoEntry {

        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =
                BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(PATH_PHOTO).build();

        public static final String COLUMN_IMAGE_ID = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
        public static final String COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME = MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME;
        public static final String COLUMN_DATA = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
        public static final String COLUMN_DESC = MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION;
        public static final String COLUMN_DATE_TAKEN = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        public static final String COLUMN_DATE_ADDED = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED;
        public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE;
        public static final String COLUMN_SIZE = MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE;
        public static final String COLUMN_ORIENTATION = MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION;
        public static final String COLUMN_HEIGHT = MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT;
        public static final String COLUMN_WIDTH = MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH;

        public static final String COLUMN_EXIF_COMMENT = "UserComment";
        public static final String COLUMN_EXIF_AUTHOR = "Author";

        public static final Map<String, String> COL_TYPES;
        static {
            COL_TYPES = new HashMap<String, String>();
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_IMAGE_ID, TARGET_MEDIASTORE);
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME, TARGET_MEDIASTORE);
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_DATA, TARGET_MEDIASTORE);
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_DESC, TARGET_MEDIASTORE);
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_DATE_TAKEN, TARGET_MEDIASTORE);
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_DATE_ADDED, TARGET_MEDIASTORE);
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_TITLE, TARGET_MEDIASTORE);
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_SIZE, TARGET_MEDIASTORE);
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_ORIENTATION, TARGET_MEDIASTORE);
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_HEIGHT, TARGET_MEDIASTORE);
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_WIDTH, TARGET_MEDIASTORE);

            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_EXIF_COMMENT, TARGET_EXIF);
            COL_TYPES.put(COLUMN_EXIF_AUTHOR, TARGET_EXIF);
        }

        public static final String CONTENT_TYPE =
                ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_PHOTO;
        public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE =
                ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE + "/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_PHOTO;

        // makes an URI to a specific image_id
        public static final Uri buildPhotoUriWithId(Long photo_id) {
            return CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(Long.toString(photo_id)).build();
        }

        // since we will "redirect" the URI towards MediaStore, we need to be able to extract IMAGE_ID
        public static Long getImageIdFromUri(Uri uri) {
            return Long.parseLong(uri.getPathSegments().get(1));  // always in position 1
        }

    }
}
```

### PhotoProvider

```
package com.example.android.galleri.app.data;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.CursorJoiner;
import android.database.CursorWindow;
import android.database.CursorWrapper;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;



public class PhotoProvider extends ContentProvider {

    // The URI Matcher used by this content provider.
    private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();

    // query: get all thumbnails, or get specific image
    static final int THUMBS = 100;
    static final int PHOTO = 101;
    static final int FIRST_PHOTO = 102;

    // update: set comment etc
    static final int PHOTO_COMMENT = 200;


    static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
        // 1) The code passed into the constructor represents the code to return for the root
        // URI.  It's common to use NO_MATCH as the code for this case. Add the constructor below.
        final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        final String authority = PhotoContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY;

        // 2) Use the addURI function to match each of the types.  Use the constants from
        // WeatherContract to help define the types to the UriMatcher.

        // get all thumbnails (with a JOIN towards MediaStore.Images, to get title and description, too)
        matcher.addURI(authority, PhotoContract.PATH_THUMBS, THUMBS);

        // matches photo (no ID). Means get first image
        matcher.addURI(authority, PhotoContract.PATH_PHOTO, FIRST_PHOTO);

        // matches photo/<any number> meaning any photo ID
        matcher.addURI(authority, PhotoContract.PATH_PHOTO + "/#", PHOTO);

        // matches photo/<photo id>/comment/ (comment text in ContentValues)
        matcher.addURI(authority, PhotoContract.PATH_PHOTO + "/#/" + PhotoContract.PATH_COMMENT, PHOTO_COMMENT);

        // 3) Return the new matcher!
        return matcher;
    }



    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {

        // Use the Uri Matcher to determine what kind of URI this is.
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

        // Note: We always return single row of data, so content-type is always "a dir"
        switch (match) {
            case PHOTO_COMMENT:
                return PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.CONTENT_TYPE;
            case PHOTO:
                return PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.CONTENT_TYPE;
            case THUMBS:
                return PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.CONTENT_TYPE;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        return true;  // enough?
    }


    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {


        // determine whether this is THUMBS or FULLSIZE query
        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (match) {

            case THUMBS: {

                // split projection into MediaStore and MediaStore.Thumbs parts
                ArrayList<String> MS_proj = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> MS_proj_thumbs = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String f : projection) {
                    if (PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COL_TYPES.get(f).equals(PhotoContract.TARGET_MEDIASTORE)) {
                        MS_proj.add(f);
                    } else {
                        MS_proj_thumbs.add(f);
                    }
                }

                String[] MS_proj_thumbs_array = new String[MS_proj_thumbs.size()];
                MS_proj_thumbs_array = MS_proj_thumbs.toArray(MS_proj_thumbs_array);

                // add _ID column to Images.Media projection, for use in JOIN
                MS_proj.add("_ID");
                String[] MS_proj_array = new String[MS_proj.size()];
                MS_proj_array = MS_proj.toArray(MS_proj_array);

                Uri baseUri;

                // first, get cursor from MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails containing all thumbnails
                baseUri = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                Log.v("JOAKIM", "Thumb: order by " + PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_DATE);
                Cursor c_thumbs = getContext().getContentResolver().query(baseUri, MS_proj_thumbs_array, null, null, PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE_ID);
                if (c_thumbs == null || !c_thumbs.moveToFirst()) {
                    Log.v("JOAKIM", "MediaStore.Thumbnails cursor contains no data...");
                    return null;
                }

                // then, get cursor from MediaStore.Images.Media (for TITLE and DESCRIPTION etc)
                // add _ID column to query
                baseUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                Cursor c_images = getContext().getContentResolver().query(baseUri, MS_proj_array, null, null, PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE_PK);
                if (c_images == null || !c_images.moveToFirst()) {
                    Log.v("JOAKIM", "MediaStore.Images cursor contains no data...");
                    return null;
                }

                // join these and return
                // the join is on images._ID = thumbnails.IMAGE_ID
                CursorJoiner joiner = new CursorJoiner(
                        c_thumbs, new String[] { PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE_ID },
                        c_images, new String[] { PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE_PK }
                );

                MatrixCursor retCursor = new MatrixCursor(projection);

                /*
                Does a join on two cursors using the specified columns.
                The cursors must already be sorted on each of the specified columns in ascending order.
                This joiner only supports the case where the tuple of key column values is unique.
                */
                for (CursorJoiner.Result joinerResult : joiner) {
                    switch (joinerResult) {
                        case LEFT:
                            // handle case where a row in cursorA is unique
                            break;
                        case RIGHT:
                            // handle case where a row in cursorB is unique
                            break;
                        case BOTH:

                            // handle case where a row with the same key is in both cursors
                            retCursor.addRow(new Object[]{
                                    c_thumbs.getLong(0),  // ID
                                    c_thumbs.getString(1), // data
                                    c_thumbs.getLong(2), // image id
                                    c_images.getString(0), // title
                                    c_images.getString(1),  // desc
                                    c_images.getLong(2)  // date
                            });
                            break;
                    }
                }


                // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065606/getcontentresolver-query-cause-cursorwrapperinner-warning
                c_thumbs.close();
                c_images.close();

                //retCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
                return retCursor;
            }


        }

        return null;
    }



}
```